Silently install InstallShield EXE file with /s not working
I got a problem of installshield 2023 Installscript project with "/s" command line.
From the link https://docs.revenera.com/installshield28helplib/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm
It shows the "setup.exe /s" should works with default "setup.iss" which in the same directory as setup.exe."
But from what I have tested, my installscript can only get "OnAbort()" event after I tried "setup.exe /s /d"  with "setup.iss" at the same directory. Is anyone can share what I have missed here ? Thanks.
step 1.Write myown installscript. enable customer action: onAbort() onBegin() SetTargetDIR().
step 2. Respond file: setup.iss - insert my responds file from /r to Disk1.
step 3. Run setup.exe to install my sample project to DUT
step 4. Make sure responds file, setup.iss, exist as expected. (same folder as setup.exe)
step 5. c:\program files(x86)\installshield installation information\{GUID} setup.exe /s /d
step 6. setup.exe ask for UAC. 
step 7. Installshield debugger got "OnAbort()" event


That code you posted is not code. [edit] to format it correctly into coherent text.

The issue only happened with "C:\Program Files(x86)\Installshield installation information{GUID}\setup.exe" .   even we place the setup.iss at the same directory. The setup.exe still trigger OnAbort() event after "setup.exe /s /d".   (Don't know why it must go with f1. setup.exe /s /d /f1"c:\123\setup.iss").  Can someone share more ?
